# などの followed by a Noun

Tags: translation, particle-の, nominalization, particle-など

Question about this sentence :

> tシャツ**などの**服を着たままプールに入らないでください。

Why do we need の? What is its use in the sentence given? Isn't など a particle so it is ok to be followed by a noun?

I checked the Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar for の and I still do not understand the use in this sentence. Pleasw help. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this sentence, "の *no*" is used to be more specific as to what kind of "thing" is being said.

For instance, if we were to remove の服, the sentence would be

> **tシャツなど**を着たままプールに入らないでください。
>
> Please do not enter the pool with **things like T-shirts, etc.**

To avoid ambiguity, "の服 *no fuku*" is added to specifically say that only clothing is not allowed, and "tシャツなど *t shatsu nado*" is added to give the reader an idea about the kind of clothing that is not allowed, hence

> **tシャツなどの服**を着たままプールに入らないでください。
>
> Please do not enter the pool with **clothing such as T-shirts, etc.**

You can find a similar sentence [here](https://www.japaneseforbeginners.info/2017/07/nado.html).